# SVG Path curve animate in opposite direction

Tags: css, animation, svg

I created an svg in adobe illustrator and used the code generated by that. I am trying to animate the svg drawing. My svg element:

```
<svg width="100px" height="100px">
    <path fill="none" d="M5,60c0-24.873,20.127-45,45-45" />
    <path fill="none" d="M95,60c0-24.873-20.127-45-45-45" />
</svg>
```

First curve is animating in clockwise direction, i want the same for the 2nd curve which is animating in anti-clockwise direction. You can see demo snippet at the end of the question.

Please explain how can i animate the 2nd path in clockwise direction. Also please explain if you can the curve data of both paths. Thanks

```css
svg {
  width: 300px;
}
svg path {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke: #50514F;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-dasharray: 870;
  stroke-dashoffset: 870;
  animation: draw 10s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="100px" height="100px">
  <path fill="none" d="M5,60c0-24.873,20.127-45,45-45" />
  <path fill="none" d="M95,60c0-24.873-20.127-45-45-45" />
</svg>
```

Comment: To change the direction of animation, you need to change the direction that the curve's points are specified in. Currently, you move to 3 oclock and draw a curve towards 12. If we reverse the path using our svg editor of choice, instead of the path commands: `M95,60c0-24.873-20.127-45-45-45`, we end up with these ones: `m 50,15 c 24.873,0 45,20.127 45,45`. If we then draw a CCW 1/2 circle from 9 oclock to 3 oclock, we get something like the following: `M 4.6428572,100.21932 C 4.6428572,80.243545 26.088068,60.94722 50,60.576463 79.088033,60.805598 95.357143,81.911631 95.357143,100.21932`

Comment: @enhzflep thanks, I used illustrator to draw an arc from 12 to 3, I got this
`<path fill="none" d="M50,15c24.873,0,45,19.009,45,42.5" />`

Can you please explain the curve data, what every value means? Thanks

Comment: No worries mate. Sure, you can see all the grammar of the SVG format right here, in the docs: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands (they explain it far better than I could hope to)

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks again :-) Also the values i got from Illustrator were a bit off, i used yours and it looks perfect.

Answer (score 3):

The second path starts in anticlockwise manner as the starting point is defined on the right of the end point.And why use complex cubic bezier curves when your requirement is just a circular arc?
You can use elliptical curves for that which are way too simple to use and handle.Change both the paths which you had defined to these two path definations and you will achieve what you want:

```
<path fill="none" d="M5,60 A50,50 0 0,1 55,10" />
<path fill="none" d="M55,10 A50,50 0 0,1 105,60"/>
```

The co-ordinates beside **M** is your starting point.values beside **A** denotes the horizontal and vertical radii respectively of your elliptical curve(both will be same as you want a circular curve). The **0** after that denotes the angle by which you want to rotate your ellipse. After that you have to provide two flags separated by a **comma**.The first flag denotes whether you want to take the shortest(**0**) or the longest(**1**) path between the starting and the ending points.The second flag denotes whether you want to take the anti-clockwise(**0**) path or the clock-wise(**0**) path between the start and the ending points(you can alter both the flags to see the changes).The last co-ordinate is your ending point,which is **55,10** for the first path and **105,60** for the second.